# What exactly is chflags opaque, nodump?

Tags: macos, terminal, metadata, tar, command-line

I've gotten to grips with the chflags man page so far, even if it's rather uncommon for man pages. Nevertheless, I find 2 parameters very peculiar. What exactly does chflags opaque and nodump do?

Manpage

> https://ss64.com/osx/chflags.html

Comment: Does this explain it https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-file-flags-modify-file-behavior-macos/ ?

Comment: How are these two distinct values related? It’s not clear what practical problem you face here.  I’ll answer with some source code, but this is likely an XY question. We don’t know what you don’t know, here. The answer to your question is basically 8, 1. It’s like you asked what happens when I set a red and green Finder tag on a file. The answer is those tags get set. That’s it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: nothing particularly relevant on modern macOS.

Long answer: both of these flags relate to Unix features that you probably never use.

- The `opaque` flag relates to "union mounts" -- mounting one filesystem over another, so that you can see the files and folders of both mixed together in (what appears to be) a single folder tree. Setting the `opaque` flag on a folder makes it... well, opaque, so if there's also a folder by the same name in the other filesystem, you won't see its contents merged in. Union mounts don't seem to work at all in recent versions of macOS, making this flag completely irrelevant.
- The `nodump` flag tells the [`dump` program](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/8/dump/) (a backup utility) that the item doesn't need to be backed up. macOS doesn't even include the `dump` program (though you could probably add it through homebrew or something). You can tell the `tar` program to skip `nodump` files with its `--nodump` options, and I suppose other backup programs could also take this as a "don't back up" flag, but I don't know of any that do this. So again this is pretty irrelevant on macOS.

Comment: IMO: The opaque flag has no meaning with respect to union mounts, because all files and directories are already opaque. However, the opaque flag does have meaning with respect to unionfs mounts when applied to directories. All of this is irrelevant with respect to macOS (Sierra through Big Sur), since macOS ignores the `-o union` option for the `mount` command and will not allow the `-t unionfs` option.

Comment: I learn so much from you and @DavidAnderson - well done

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks, I've updated by answer a bit. BTW, I tried using `mount -o union` on High Sierra, and it doesn't give an error and does list `union` when I list mounted volumes with `mount`, but the option seems to have no other effect (i.e. I don't actually see files & folders from the underlying filesystem).

Comment: Gordon: I agree with you that with High Sierra the `mount` command will accept the `-o option`, but then ignores the option. In your answer, you seem confused about the `opaque` flag. Putting a `opaque` flag on a file has no effect. Files are always opaque. Folders may not necessarily be opaque. When a folder is not opaque, added the `opaque` flag will make the folder opaque.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Ah, I think I see what you mean. Better now?

Comment: Gordon: Yes, the answer is better now.

Comment: I believe `borg` backup honors nodump on macos.

Answer (score 8):

The `nodump` file flag can still be used by macOS. Apparently, the `opaque` file flag has never been used by macOS or OS X since at least Snow Leopard.

---

**Here is an example of the use of the `nodump` file flag.**

Below is the output from the command `ls -lO hi.txt bye.txt`. Note `bye.txt` has the `nodump` flag.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 davidanderson  staff  nodump 8 Mar 20 12:13 bye.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 davidanderson  staff  -      9 Mar 20 12:13 hi.txt
```

Next, the command `tar --nodump -cf mytarball hi.txt bye.txt` is executed to create the archive file `mytarball`. Afterwards, if the command `tar -tvf mytarball` is entered, the contents of the archive will be printed. Below is the output.

```
-rw-r--r--  0 davidanderson staff       9 Mar 20 12:13 hi.txt
```

Note that the file `bye.txt` was omitted from the archive because of the `nodump` flag.

---

**Here is an example of the use of the `opaque` file flag.**

> While I can provide an example, the example will not work with macOS. Instead the example will use the current version of FreeBSD.

The macOS operating system is derived from parts of BSD Unix. BSD implements two forms of unioning: the `-o union` option to the mount command and the `mount_unionfs` command. When testing various versions of OS X and macOS, I found Snow Leopard does implement the `-o union` option, while High Sierra and Big Sur ignore this option. All three versions do not include the `mount_unionfs` command. AFAIK, the `opaque` file flag is only used by this latter form of unioning. So to provide an example, I will turn to FreeBSD, which does include the `mount_unionfs` command.

> The basic idea here is to allow modifications to be made to a read-only mount. In the following example, I will remove a directory containing a file, then create a new empty directory with the same name.

In this example, I have a DVD with two directories named `dog` and `cat`. The directory `dog` contains the file `poodle` and the directory `cat` contains the file `siamese`. After putting the DVD in the optical drive, I entered the following commands as root user to mount the DVD and view the contents. The current directory is the root user's home directory `/root`.

```
mkdir pets
mount -t cd9660 /dev/cd0 pets
ls -lRFo pets
```

Below is the sample output.

[image]

To allow modifications, I created and mounted the empty directory `changes` using the `-t unionfs` option. Also, I printed out the mounts to `pets`. The `mount` command actually uses the `mount_unionfs` command to perform the mount.

```
mkdir changes
mount -t unionfs changes pets
mount | grep pets
```

Below is sample output.

[image]

Next, I used the commands below remove the directory named `dog` and confirm the change.

```
rm -fr pets/dog
ls -lRFo pets
ls -lRFo changes
```

Below is a sample output. Note that the directory `dog` no longer appears in directory `pets`. Also, the directory `changes` appears to have only gained the empty directory `cat`.

[image]

However, a whiteout named `dog` was added to the directory `changes` and thus the directory `pets`. To see the whiteout, the `-W` option needs to be added to the `ls` command, as shown below.

```
ls -lRFoW pets
ls -lRFoW changes
```

Below is a sample output.

[image]

The whiteout `dog` masks the directory `dog` on the DVD. Next, I used the commands below to create a new empty directory named `dog` and show the changes.

```
mkdir pets/dog
ls -lRFoW pets
ls -lRFoW changes
```

Below is a sample output.

[image]

Here, the whiteout `dog` was replaced by the directory `dog` with the `opaque` file flag set. This directory masks the directory `dog` on the DVD. To demonstrate the need for the `opaque` file flag, I used the commands shown below to remove the `opaque` file flag and show the results.

```
chflags noopaque changes/dog
ls -lRFoW pets
ls -lRFoW changes
```

Below is a sample output.

[image]

Without the `opaque` file flag, the file `poodle` ***incorrectly*** appears in the `pets/dog` directory.

The final commands below just undo all the mounts and changes made in this example.

```
umount pets
umount pets
ls -lRFoW pets
ls -lRFoW changes
rmdir pets
rm -fr changes
```

Below is a sample output.

[image]

---

### References

[Unioning file systems: Architecture, features, and design choices](https://lwn.net/Articles/324291/)
[Union file systems: Implementations, part I](https://lwn.net/Articles/325369/)
[Wikipedia: macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS)
[Unionfs: document reasons for opaque directories](https://lists.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/pipermail/unionfs-cvs/2008-March/003404.html)
[FreeBSD ls command](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ls)
[FreeBSD mount command](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)
[FreeBSD mount_unionfs command](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount_unionfs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)

Note: FreeBSD was executed by first downloading the [virtual machine ready file](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/VM-IMAGES/12.2-RELEASE/amd64/Latest/) named `FreeBSD-12.2-RELEASE-amd64.vmdk.xz`. This file was used to create a VirtualBox virtual machine with a 2013 iMac as host. This file should also be compatible with VMware Fusion Player.

Answer (score 3):

They are [POSIX standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) flags defined in [stat.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/stat.h.auto.html) and any unix program can read them with the stat call and the system writes and removes them in a standard pattern for compatibility with the dump and unionfs functionality.

```c
/*
 * Definitions of flags stored in file flags word.
 *
 * Super-user and owner changeable flags.
 */
#define UF_SETTABLE 0x0000ffff  /* mask of owner changeable flags */
#define UF_NODUMP   0x00000001  /* do not dump file */
#define UF_IMMUTABLE    0x00000002  /* file may not be changed */
#define UF_APPEND   0x00000004  /* writes to file may only append */
#define UF_OPAQUE   0x00000008  /* directory is opaque wrt. union */
/*
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment bmike.
But if I'm honest I don't quite understand. What do these commands really do, do you have an example?

If I set the "opaque" or the "nodump" flag on a file, what exactly happens to the file? What changes?

Comment: The OS stores bits of metadata in the filesystem.  That’s it @DarwinOSX I didn’t add anything else since nothing else happens. That’s why this is an XY question, you’re not being clear what problem you face. If you can’t set or read the bits, that is a practical question we can answer.