# Avoid changes to /etc/pam.d/sudo across macOS updates?

Tags: macos, software-update, sudo, command-line

I have a custom `/etc/pam.d/sudo` setup and I noticed that the file was always reset to default when macOS updates itself.

How do I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Q: "How do I prevent that from happening?"

You ***can*** prevent Apple's Updates from performing a *"reset to default"* with the `chflags` command. Open a terminal, and make the following entry:

```shell
sudo chflags simmutable /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

This sets the system-level *immutable* flag on the named file; synonyms for `simmutable` are `schg` and `schange`.

See `man chflags` for details and options. Importantly, understand that when you need to edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo` again, you must first *clear* the *immutable* flag as follows:

```shell
sudo chflags nosimmutable /etc/pam.d/sudo
```

To list/show the flags, use `ls -lO`.

##### Notes:

I've tested this on my Ventura system during my recent update to *ver* 13.6, and it (finally) prevented Apple's OS Update from *reverting* (resetting to default) my `/etc/auto_master` file - as it had done during two previous updates. Consequently, I believe it will work on all `/etc` files, and perhaps others that are similarly *reverted* during Apple's macOS Updates. However: Updates are rather infrequent, so feedback from others who use `chflags` is appreciated.

The `chflags` utility has been around since about 1994 (BSD 4.4). However, `man chflags` has a 2018 date, possibly suggesting that the utility has been recently updated. Also, `man chflags` states there are only a few utilities that are *"chflags-aware"* - including `install` and `restore`.

The *flags* that are set/cleared by `chflags` are stored in file metadata in a structure that is very similar to the structures containing *ownership* and *mode* data. Each structure is manipulated by its own utility: `chown` for *ownership*, `chmod` for *mode/permissions* and `chflags` for *flags*.

*flags* are similar to *mode/permissions*, but apply different types of permissions across all user classes. Whereas *mode/permissions* are set for each class of user (owner, group, everyone), a *flag* applies to all users - even `root`! For example, the `simmutable` flag means no changes may be made to the file by anyone; even the owner must remove the flag before making a change to it. This feature can create confusion, for example, when a user cannot change a file even with `sudo`. Note that the `ls -lO` command may be used to reveal flag settings.

I learned of the `chflags` utility from @ArjanVlaanderen in an answer he posted to [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/464633/149366). I posted a [question similar to this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464436/why-do-os-updates-overwrite-etc-files) recently which was closed as a *duplicate*. I was not satisfied with the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443164/149366) to this question, and so this is my attempt to answer.

Following are a few references on `chflags`:

- [How to Use File Flags to Modify File Behavior in macOS](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-file-flags-modify-file-behavior-macos/)
- [Apple's Documentation Archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/chflags.2.html)
- [POSIX standard flags defined in stat.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/stat.h.auto.html); from this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/416140/149366) in Apple SE.
- [Locking and Unlocking Files](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/0596004605/ch01s08.html), from 'Mac OSX Hacks' by O'Reilly.
- [Changing file permissions on macOS (and using flags)](https://linux-audit.com/changing-file-permissions-on-macos-and-using-flags/)
- [Python os.chflags() Method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chflags.htm) - for Python programmers :)
- [`chattr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr) - Wikipedia article comparing Linux `chattr` to Apple/BSD `chflags`.

Answer (score 4):

macOS Sonoma adds an include for `sudo_local` to the top of `/etc/pam.d/sudo`:

```
# sudo: auth account password session
auth       include        sudo_local
auth       sufficient     pam_smartcard.so
auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
account    required       pam_permit.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_permit.so
```

According to `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local.template`, this `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local` won't be overwritten by system updates:

```
# sudo_local: local config file which survives system update and is included for sudo
# uncomment following line to enable Touch ID for sudo
#auth       sufficient     pam_tid.so
```

As long as you're only wanting to add new lines to the top of `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, you should be able to create `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local` and add your customisations there (or if it's just the `pam_tid.so` tweak, you can copy `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local.template` to `/etc/pam.d/sudo_local` and uncomment out the appropriate line).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prevent it, you will have to check if it has changed and restore your custom file when you detect the change.

Comment: @Seamus There is thread in [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/14637?answerId=44637022#44637022) with alleged response to bug report: "This is expected behavior. We can’t possibly know whether the custom changes that have been made to this file are still valid under the new major OS, and we have to deliver an OS which functions correctly out-of-the-box. Advanced users such as yourself will understand how to put it back." :-)