# Why do OS updates overwrite /etc files?

Tags: software-update, autofs

This has happened twice now: After *updating* my Ventura OS, I find that files in `/etc` are over-written with the original, default contents.

Specifically, I have modified the file `/etc/auto_master` to use Apple's **AutoFS** feature. After each OS update, this file is over-written with the original/default file. It's a small file, and my modifications are not extensive, but it's fairly inconvenient and irritating. In fact, it's so arrogant that I wonder if I've not *missed something*...

Have I missed Apple's explanation or work-around to this behavior?

#### NOTE:

This question specifically inquires about reversions to `/etc` files following an ***UPDATE***. The answer given to the ["duplicate question"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427277/avoid-changes-to-etc-pam-d-sudo-across-macos-updates) is apparently based on a Q&A based on an ***UPGRADE***. AFAIK, the logic for file reversions should be different for UPDATES and UPGRADES.

Comment: It is every UPDATE because the SSV gets replaced on every update. The UPGRADE behaviour only applies pre (I think) Big Sur.

Comment: re Upgrade and Update have you got any source for the process being different?

Comment: Your assumption about differences between updates and upgrades in regard of /etc is most likely not correct. I have files there (e.g. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/000-local.conf` or `/etc/paths.d/*`) which never get overwritten, and others (like `auto_master`) which get overwritten with each update/upgrade.

Comment: @mmmmmm: All I have is the [reference to the Apple Developer's Exchange Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/14637?answerId=44637022#44637022) referenced in the "duplicate question".

Comment: @nohillside: If that's how you feel, I have to say I'm surprised that you wouldn't vote to re-open this question. If my assumption is *faulty*, and yours is correct, then it remains true that the "duplicate question" is not actually a duplicate. All I'm trying to learn is whether or not there is some logic (or documentation) or thought behind Apple's decision to revert the files.

Comment: @Gilby: I assume you have a **reference** upon which the statement in your comment is based?? If you could share it with us, it may be the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: The answer to the original question ("You cannot prevent it, you will have to check if it has changed and restore your custom file when you detect the change.") fits the upgrade and the update case, *even* if there would be a difference in the process. The implied "why" question is off-topic, as are most questions about why Apple does or doesn't do things the way they do/don't.

Comment: PS: Specifically for `auto_master` I have a short shell script which reinstalls my custom version if necessary.

Comment: The reference is 8 years old and several OS versions old - there have been major changes - also tyhe last major version change Ventura used the same mechanisim as a minor version change in Mavericks. So they are the same now as far as I can see.

Comment: @nohillside: You're ignoring the real question stated near the end: `"Have I missed Apple's explanation or work-around to this behavior?"`. But I expect you're ignoring it for other reasons. Let's forget the review request - I can see now it's a waste of time.